# Game playing on both screens

Tags: 13.04, games, monitor, steam

I have dual monitors setup on 13.04 with an ATI card using the propitiatory driver.

In install Steam then Amnesia and started the game up. The displays are mirroring instead of the game just playing on one. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings > Displays.

Tick the checkbox "Mirror Displays" on middle right hand side.